# Strange Java cast exception. Why can't I cast Long to a Float?

Tags: java, casting

Why can't I cast Long to a Float?

I get this error message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

Why is this a problem? The numbers that I'm trying to cast are decimals in the domain [-10.0, 10.0]. They start out as Object instances returned using `JFormattedTextField.getValue()`. But they must be converted to floats.

### Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
    at submodeler.animation.Timeline.setKeyedAttribute(Timeline.java:59)
    at submodeler.ui.attributes.TransformationAttributePanel.actionPerformed(TransformationAttributePanel.java:247)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6348)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6113)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4714)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2143)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4618)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4282)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4212)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2129)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2475)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4544)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:635)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: eventually provide the sourcecode around Timeline.java:59 to find a solution.

Comment: This is what's happening in Timeline:

public void setKeyedAttribute(int position, String property, Object value){
lastIndex = addKeyFrameAt(position);
keyframes.get(lastIndex).setAttribute(property, value);
}

However, now I have changed it to require a float type for the value input parameter. And that (combined with kdgregory's response) has solved the problem.

thanks!

Answer (score 17):

It would help if you provide a stacktrace.

Otherwise, the standard solution is to replace `(Float) someLongValue` with `someLongValue.floatValue()`

If you are dealing with primitive types, you can just cast from long to float, although it is a [5.1.2 Widening Primitive Conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html), but one that may lose precision, so be careful! Obviously you have the wrapper type [Long](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html), which cannot implicitly be converted, thus you get the classcastexception. This may be because of [autoboxing](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html), or explicit Long object creation.

Some more uninvited advice: if your valid values are decimals in the range of -10 to +10 the standard data type is `int` (primitive). avoid float if you mean exact numbers. `long` is also not optimal, because it is not fully atomic like int and it takes 2x the memory. If you allow a different state "not assigned" then `Integer`, which may take null, is also OK.

Comment: It's basically that, you can't typecast two incompatible classes.  Autoboxing does NOT work its magic to unbox the number and then box it as the other number.  You absolutely need to get the value from it and I'd recommend doing something like: Float.valueOf(long.floatValue());.

Comment: if autoboxing is enabled, Float.valueOf(long.floatValue()) and just long.floatValue() should be equally good.

Comment: I forget the specifics of autoboxing, but if it does: "new Float(long.floatValue())" instead of "Float.valueOf(long.floatValue())" then the former will consume more memory than needed.  However they're really close.

Comment: take a look at the source of java.lang.Float (line 404 in 1.6): 

 public static Float valueOf(float f) {
        return new Float(f);
    }

Comment: @Malaxeur - it is implementation specific whether autoboxing will be equivalent to "new Float(long.floatValue())" or "Float.valueOf(long.floatValue())", but as @Andreas points out, this is moot for Java 1.6.  For other types (e.g. Integer) it is not moot, but the Java 1.6 compiler generates calls to Integer.valueOf in that case.

Answer (score 10):

The exception happens because the compiler recognizes that Long and Float do not have a parent-child dependency. Unlike C++, which will try to find an overloaded cast operator.

You can call doubleValue() on any of the primitive wrapper types that are derived from Number, so this is the recommended way to do what you want:

```
double val = ((Number)textField.getValue()).doubleValue()
```

A couple of things to note here: first, I casted the output of getValue() to Number. That way, you can change your mind and actually return Double values in the future, and you won't break.

Also, I'm using double values, not float. The JVM works with double internally, so there's no reason to use float except to save space in an array.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, converting long to float is as easy as this:

```
float f = (float)myLongVar;
```

I have no experience in using `JFormattedTextField`, but you can try type-casting the returned object to String, use `.substring()` to get the exact value, and type-cast it to long. This may not be the right approach, but it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Long l = ...
Float f = new Float ((float)l.longValue());
```

i.e., you have to transform your Long to a primitive (i.e. non-object) type.

Comment: I tried this first. It threw the same cast exception. It comes directly from JFormattedTextField. So I cannot 'create' a Long first. I'm even setting values to the JFormattedTextField as Float values.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert machine bit-representations of float/double to/from bytes, see [Double.doubleToLongBits](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) and [Float.floatToIntBits](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html) and associated functions.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was converting a JSONObject to a Java Object. I had to change my code from `double a = (double) json.get("myJSONKey");` to the following:

```
try {
  double a = Double.parseDouble((String) myJSONObject.get("myJSONKey"));
} catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
  System.err.out("I could not convert it to a double!! :(");
}
```

Note you don't have to do the try/catch but I like to just so I'm clean :).

In the event you already have a long value (or int or whatever) then use `String.valueOf(myInt)` to get your string.

Hope this helps,

-Andrew

Comment: After reviewing this more, @Andreas answer would be more performance savvy if you already have your primitive data type because Strings are memory hogs.